# JMeter - Multiple users reading requests from a directory

Tags: jmeter

I have a directory of XML files, and I wanted to configure Jmeter such a way that multiple users(threads) should be able to read the XML files(SOAP requests) concurrently (in a round-robin way or some other way) and submit them to Web Service Endpoint, which means I wanted them to share the input files.. for example if my directory contains 100 XML files then all of my configured users(threads) should share the load and jointly have to process the XML files. (Each user should not process all the 100 files independently).

Is there any way to test the above scenario?

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter) plugin would be the easiest option to use

[image: JMeter Directory Listing Config]

Just provide path to the directory where your XML files live, configure the plugin according to your test scenario and that's it, you will be able to use just one [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and refer the file name (or path) as `${filename}` where required.

You can install Directory Listing Config plugin and keep it up-to-date via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/).